# React: Function not reading updated global variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Run button has already been clicked.**
When I click on the **skip button** I am unable to reach Switch Case 2. The component state skip gets updated but the function still prints the old value of skip.

```
const Component = () => {

const [skip, setskip] = useState(false);
const [runstate, setrunstate] = useState(1);
    
const run = async () => {
        switch(runstate) {

           case 1: {
             if(skip) {
                setrunstate(2);
             }
             else {
                console.log(skip , "Stuck in Step 1")  // false, Stuck in Step 1 even after clicking skip
                setTimeout(run, 250)
             }
             break;
           }
           
           case 2: {
             console.log("Reached Step 2")
          }
        }
    }

return (
     <>
        <button onClick={run}> Run </button>
        <button onClick={() => setskip(true)}> Skip </button>
     </>
    )
}
```

Can anybody tell what might be causing this or a correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Where have you called the `run` function? Please complete the code snippet. And what do you mean by these phrases **runstate 2** and **still stuck in 1**? Reframe your question in a better way.

Comment: @VinaySharma made the updates. Please check now

Comment: Okay so you by **Switch Case 2** you mean to say **console.log("Reached Step 2")** should work, right? How would the **case 2** work unless you don't increment `runstate` to `2`?

Comment: @VinaySharma Clicking skip should set skip to true -> **case1** if block should execute on next recursion  => runstate should be set to 2 -> **case2** should be executed. Now skip is being set to true still the if block in **case1** doesn't get executed on subsequent recursions

Comment: Why would **if block in case1** execute? Run function is executed before `runState` is even set to true as you have **already clicked run button before the skip one**.

Comment: @VinaySharma there is a recursion occurring in **case1 else block** which calls run function again in 250ms, please read the snippet carefully.

Comment: okay, and why is the function kept asynchronous?

Comment: @VinaySharma that is because an API call will happen in **case2**

Comment: Alright, I understood the issue! I'll work on the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why recursion is not working?

There are a lot of factors behind this. So, let's understand with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your use case and breaking the code step-by-step.

```
const [foo, setFoo] = useState(0);

const recursiveCallback = useCallback(() => {
  setFoo(foo + 1);

  // an infinite recursion occurs as
  // termination condition never satisfies
  if (foo <= 2) {
    // current reference is being called
    // with the current value of foo in
    // the scope, i.e. lexical environment
    recursiveCallback();
  }
}, [foo]);

return (
  <>
    <p>{foo}</p>
    <button onClick={recursiveCallback}>Recursive Callback</button>
  </>
);
```

When `recursiveCallback()` is called for the very first time, a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) is created with the `foo`'s value being 0.

When `foo` is incremented with `setFoo(foo + 1)`, a new reference of `recursiveCallback` is created in the memory (let's say **x**) which would have the updated value of `foo` in it.

Now, when `recursiveCallback()` is called again, it does not call the **x** reference of itself but the current reference from where it's being called from, which would have the value of `foo` present in the **lexical environment**, i.e. 0. So, it **appears** that  `foo` is not incrementing but in actual it is, as you can see in the `<p>{foo}</p>`.

So, the solution to fix the above snippet would be to call the function in a `useEffect` which would always call a **new reference** of `nonRecursiveCallback` every time the value of `foo` is updated!

```
// note that the function is no more recursive
const nonRecursiveCallback = useCallback(() => {
  // updated foo is logged
  console.log(foo);

  // incrementing foo
  setFoo(foo + 1);
}, [foo]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (foo && foo <= 2) {
    // new reference is being called
    // with an updated value of foo
    nonRecursiveCallback();
  }
}, [foo, nonRecursiveCallback]);
```

#### Solution

Instead of calling `run()` **recursively**, you can have it called **repetitively** with the help of `useEffect` hook unless the termination condition is not satisfied.

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useCallback } = React;

const Component = () => {
  const [skip, setSkip] = useState(false);
  const [runState, setRunState] = useState(1);

  // two additional local states have been introduced
  // which would help trigger useEffect repetitively
  // after user has clicked on run button
  const [runEffect, setRunEffect] = useState(false);
  const [toggleEffect, setToggleEffect] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (runEffect) {
      switch (runState) {
        case 1: {
          if (skip) {
            setRunState(2);
          } else {
            console.log(skip, 'Stuck in Step 1');

            // toggle a boolean value which
            // would trigger this hook again
            setTimeout(() => setToggleEffect(!toggleEffect), 250);
          }
          break;
        }

        case 2: {
          console.log('Reached Step 2');
          setRunEffect(false);
          break;
        }

        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }, [runEffect, toggleEffect, runState, skip]);

  const startRecursion = useCallback(() => {
    setRunEffect(true);
    setToggleEffect(true);
  }, []);

  const handleSkip = useCallback(() => {
    setSkip(true);
  }, []);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={startRecursion}>Run</button>
      <button onClick={handleSkip}>Skip</button>
    </ React.Fragment>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Component />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```